# How to control output to jmeter .jtl log file

Tags: user-interface, jmeter, command-line-interface

I created a JMeter test plan for testing Tibco EMS messaging. It contains 1 JMS Message publisher and 5 JMS Message Subscriber samplers.  I can run it easily via the JMeter GUI with 60,000 EMS messages without issue.  However, it crawls then stalls at about 2,000 messages  when I run it in Command Line Mode (CLI) using the local command below:

```
 C:\jmeter\apache-jmeter-2.9\bin\jmeter.bat -n -r -t  C:\jmeter\apache-jmeter-2.9\bin\EMS-85-TestPlan.jmx  -l  C:\jmeter\apache-jmeter-2.9\logs\EMS-85-JMeterGUIStats.jtl
```

The resulting .jtl file is 88,600 lines.  I removed the .jtl command option and the test finished as fast as the gui test.

How can I configure JMeter to update the .jtl file for only the "JMS Message publisher" samples?  I think this will resolve my bottleneck and still provide the required reporting.

Comment: Yes, I use GUI mode to teak the test, then disable any reporting listeners and run it via CLI mode for the actual test.  I will make a thread dump as requested.

Ahh, I have run a lot of tests so I will report the actual end condition with the jtl log file results.  

There may be another way to resolve this issue.  Is it possible to configure a JMeter sampler to execute but not report the results?  I need the 5 JMS Message Subscriber samplers to purge messages from the queue but I don't care about their reporting.  Hopefully, this would avoid these updates to the .jtl log or via the gui.

Answer (score 0):

Using GUI mode for load testing is not a Best-Practice.

It is possible that when you run it in GUI mode, the load is lower than in NON GUI.
In this case what you are facing may be revealing an issue in the application you are testing.

Could you make a thread dump of JMeter instance when it "stalls" .

Also I don't understand what you are saying about the 88600 lines, so does it stall or not ?

You can control the reporting by scoping the listener under the Thread Group you want to report, you could maje View Results Tree output to file for example.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the stalled test.  I ran the test that should send 20,000 messages to one topic which sends to 4 queues.  It stalled after 902 actual samples were sent.  The link below shows a folder with the thread dump, .jmx test plan, and the .jtl file: [GoogleFiles](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7-SwoTVeWFaY2Z0cnBkb2NzMFU&usp=sharing).

Comment: Oh, I noticed "Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread" errors on our remote jmeter grid servers so I increased each of the jmeter max HEAP settings to 1 MB.  A simple test worked and will test more.  I still would like to know if you can optimize the plan, perhaps by removing the JMS Subscriber logging to the .jtl file if possible.